# Merging array of objects and string state to new object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects like this:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {type: "", label: "first name", title: "", name: "sa", uniquekey: "", …}
1: {type: "text", label: "first name", title: "", name: "asdasd", uniquekey: "", …}
lastIndex: (...)
lastItem: (...)
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

This data is being received from parent component.

Also, in my react state,

```
this.state = {
  data: this.props.newdata,
  formname: '',
  finalData: {}
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is when I click a `onChange()` field handler in child component, it sets a value for state `formname`. The on clicking form `onSubmit()` handler, I want to merge both `formname` and `data` state into state `finalData` in the form of an object.

I tried using using `map()` like this, but got confused:

```
onSubmit = (e) => {   
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('TEST FORM', this.state.data);
      console.log('TEST FORM NAME', this.state.formname);

      // console.log(this.setState({
      //   newform: [...this.state.newform, this.state.formname]
      // }), 'added form name');

      var finalData = this.state.data.map((item, i) => {
        return {
          form: item
        };
      });
      console.log(formField);

      this.setState({ finalData:finalData })
}
```

I want to look it something like this:

```
{
   0:{
     formname1:'',
     [ 0: {a:'', b:''},
       1: {a:'', b:''},
     ]
   },
   1:{
     formname2:'',
     [ 0: {a:'', b:''},
       1: {a:'', b:''},
     ]
   },
.......
}
```

Kindly help out

Comment: How exactly looks your data structure before and how should it look afterwards? It's not clear, what you want to merge

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 updated. Kindly check

Comment: @bubble-cord, this is not an object. Where is the key for the array.

Comment: Question is not clear. `formname1` and `formname2` are not a part of initial state. Where are they coming from? Do you mind editing the state?

Comment: I want it to get stored into an object

Comment: @METALHEAD formname1 and formname 2 is the name I am providing via onChange handler, then need it to get stored with my props.data (which is an array of objects) into a new object, every time.

Comment: Just edited my answer....Look into it

Answer (score 1):

```
const finalData = {...this.state.data, formname: this.state.formname};
```

or

```
const finalData = {[this.state.formname]: this.state.data};
```

?

Comment: If I add multiple data with different form names like 'form1' and then 'form2' in addition to their data, it only stores 'form2' and corresponding data, over-riding form1

Comment: Your state has `formname` outside the `data` array.

Comment: That's what I need to do. Add state `formname` along with `data` array into a new single object everytime on each click, so that they appear as single data.

Answer (score 1):

I did'nt understand your exact question. I am making an assumption that the formname is stored in `this.state.formname` and the array is stored in `this.state.data`. The required object can be easily generated as below:

```
onSubmit = (e) => {   

  e.preventDefault();

  // Cloning the finalData Object from state. You do not want to mutate directly
  const finalDataClone =  {...this.state.finalData};


   //Now push the dynamic object to the clone. 
   //The numbers that you mentioned in your example object are dynamically generated here based on object length.

  var objSize = Object.keys(finalDataClone).length;

  finalDataClone[objSize] = {
          [`formName${objSize-1}`] : this.state.formname,
          dataArray : {...this.state.data}
  }


 // Set the state here
      this.setState((prevState)=>{
        return {
           finalData : finalDataClone
        }
      })

}
```

So, above basically generates dynamic key value pairs.

Also, just for your information, since `setState()` is async operation, React recommends to use  [updater function](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) inside the `setState()`

Comment: If you feel this answer as correct, you can accept this as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Should it be something like this?

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    finalData: [
        ...prevState.finalData,
        {
            formname: this.state.formname,
            data: [...this.state.data]
        }
    ]
}));
```